# Why didn't Spinel find out about Rose Quartz before the broadcast?

Tags: steven-universe

In Steven Universe: the Movie, Spinel is clueless about Pink's abandonment until the message. However, the Diamonds definitely knew about Spinel, and Pink's shattering wasn't a secret, so why didn't they tell her? Steven asks that, "You've met the Diamonds before, right?" And Spinel responds, "Yeah, but," meaning the Diamonds knew that she existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Diamonds have seen Spinel before, we can see that when Pink is offered her first colony just before the drift away song. She is playing in the background and pushes into the shot at some points. Pink then abandons her in the Garden and that is the last communication she has until the message from steven. She didn't know about pink being shattered until that message.

Comment: so did _all_ of the diamonds forget about her?

Comment: What is it about the diamonds that makes you think they would waste even a second thinking of Spinel?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan I mean, if Blue was so obsessed over not shattering the Rose Quartzes, because "they were _hers_," wouldn't she also want Spinel? I understand completely that Yellow and White wouldn't give a bit about her.